# merge lines in xml based on a character python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I have multiple xml files, these are xml version of a PDF document. Firstly, I have to merge the xml files and then read the word that ends with an hyphen. If a word ends with an hyphen there is a separate tag created in XML (TCL CHAR = '-'), I need to identify these tag and merge the last word of the previous line and first word of the next line which is in a separate tag called . I have the following codes for merge

```
def run(files):
first = None
for filename in files:
    data = ET.parse(filename).getroot()
    if first is None:
        first = data
    else:
        first.extend(data)
if first is not None:
    root = ET.tostring(first)
return root
```

and the following code for word merge

`beg_line_cont = []
end_line_cont = []
for block in root:
    for para in block:
        for line in para:
            for word in line:
                if word.tag == 'TC':
                    line = word.text
                if word.tag == 'TCL' and word.attrib['CHAR']=='-':
                    beg_line_cont.append(line)
                    if word.tag == 'TC':
                        line = word.text
                        end_line_cont.append(line)`

The merge code is not working, I am able to the previous line before the TCL CHAR = '-' but not the next line... Can someone assist??

XML File sample is here:

```
</PAR>
<LPAR PBDPL="[D]137[L]120" PBCAMGTI="[G]LP6[T]Lead VJ" STRIKE="0"></LPAR>
<PAR PBDPL="[D]3360[P]3m" PBCAMGTI="[G]I2AS[I]0" TAPARADV="[HYP]1" BLMODE="3" STRIKE="0" UNIQID="d180d82ee84ff937">
<LINE>
<FRMDEF NAME="ROMAN" PNTSZSTR="" FONTNAME="" FACE="R" SETWIDTHSTR="" SLANTSTR="" BASESTR="" COLORSTR="" SCREENSTR="" SMALLCAPS="2" ALLCAPS="2" KNOCKOUT="2" ENDFRM="0" SAVFRM="1" UNDLEAD1="" UNDLEAD2="" UNDTHICK1="" UNDTHICK2="" UNDCOLOR="" UNDSCREEN="" UNDLKNOCKOUT="1"/>
<TC>Diese Angebotsunterlage (die &#132;</TC>
<FRMDEF NAME="ROMAN" PNTSZSTR="" FONTNAME="" FACE="R" SETWIDTHSTR="" SLANTSTR="" BASESTR="" COLORSTR="" SCREENSTR="" SMALLCAPS="2" ALLCAPS="2" KNOCKOUT="2" ENDFRM="1" SAVFRM="0" UNDLEAD1="" UNDLEAD2="" UNDTHICK1="" UNDTHICK2="" UNDCOLOR="" UNDSCREEN="" UNDLKNOCKOUT="1"/>
<FRMDEF NAME="BOLD" PNTSZSTR="" FONTNAME="" FACE="B" SETWIDTHSTR="" SLANTSTR="" BASESTR="" COLORSTR="" SCREENSTR="" SMALLCAPS="2" ALLCAPS="2" KNOCKOUT="2" ENDFRM="0" SAVFRM="1" UNDLEAD1="" UNDLEAD2="" UNDTHICK1="" UNDTHICK2="" UNDCOLOR="" UNDSCREEN="" UNDLKNOCKOUT="1"/>
<TC>Angebotsunterlage</TC>
<FRMDEF NAME="BOLD" PNTSZSTR="" FONTNAME="" FACE="B" SETWIDTHSTR="" SLANTSTR="" BASESTR="" COLORSTR="" SCREENSTR="" SMALLCAPS="2" ALLCAPS="2" KNOCKOUT="2" ENDFRM="1" SAVFRM="0" UNDLEAD1="" UNDLEAD2="" UNDTHICK1="" UNDTHICK2="" UNDCOLOR="" UNDSCREEN="" UNDLKNOCKOUT="1"/>
<FRMDEF NAME="ROMAN" PNTSZSTR="" FONTNAME="" FACE="R" SETWIDTHSTR="" SLANTSTR="" BASESTR="" COLORSTR="" SCREENSTR="" SMALLCAPS="2" ALLCAPS="2" KNOCKOUT="2" ENDFRM="0" SAVFRM="1" UNDLEAD1="" UNDLEAD2="" UNDTHICK1="" UNDTHICK2="" UNDCOLOR="" UNDSCREEN="" UNDLKNOCKOUT="1"/>
<TC>&#147;) beschreibt das freiwillige &#246;ffentliche &#220;bernahme</TC>
<TCL CHAR="-" WIDTH="67" CTLCHAR="-" CTLSTR="" TYPE="SYSTEMHYPHEN" VISIBLE="1" USE_SF_LDRVALUES="1"/></LINE>
<LINE>
<TC>angebot in Form eines Tauschangebots (das &#132;</TC>
<FRMDEF NAME="ROMAN" PNTSZSTR="" FONTNAME="" FACE="R" SETWIDTHSTR="" SLANTSTR="" BASESTR="" COLORSTR="" SCREENSTR="" SMALLCAPS="2" ALLCAPS="2" KNOCKOUT="2" ENDFRM="1" SAVFRM="0" UNDLEAD1="" UNDLEAD2="" UNDTHICK1="" UNDTHICK2="" UNDCOLOR="" UNDSCREEN="" UNDLKNOCKOUT="1"/>
<FRMDEF NAME="BOLD" PNTSZSTR="" FONTNAME="" FACE="B" SETWIDTHSTR="" SLANTSTR="" BASESTR="" COLORSTR="" SCREENSTR="" SMALLCAPS="2" ALLCAPS="2" KNOCKOUT="2" ENDFRM="0" SAVFRM="1" UNDLEAD1="" UNDLEAD2="" UNDTHICK1="" UNDTHICK2="" UNDCOLOR="" UNDSCREEN="" UNDLKNOCKOUT="1"/>
<TC>Angebot</TC>
<FRMDEF NAME="BOLD" PNTSZSTR="" FONTNAME="" FACE="B" SETWIDTHSTR="" SLANTSTR="" BASESTR="" COLORSTR="" SCREENSTR="" SMALLCAPS="2" ALLCAPS="2" KNOCKOUT="2" ENDFRM="1" SAVFRM="0" UNDLEAD1="" UNDLEAD2="" UNDTHICK1="" UNDTHICK2="" UNDCOLOR="" UNDSCREEN="" UNDLKNOCKOUT="1"/>
<FRMDEF NAME="ROMAN" PNTSZSTR="" FONTNAME="" FACE="R" SETWIDTHSTR="" SLANTSTR="" BASESTR="" COLORSTR="" SCREENSTR="" SMALLCAPS="2" ALLCAPS="2" KNOCKOUT="2" ENDFRM="0" SAVFRM="1" UNDLEAD1="" UNDLEAD2="" UNDTHICK1="" UNDTHICK2="" UNDCOLOR="" UNDSCREEN="" UNDLKNOCKOUT="1"/>
<TC>&#147;) der ADO Properties S.A., einer Aktiengesell</TC>
<TCL CHAR="-" WIDTH="67" CTLCHAR="-" CTLSTR="" TYPE="SYSTEMHYPHEN" VISIBLE="1" USE_SF_LDRVALUES="1"/></LINE>
<LINE>
<TC>schaft nach luxemburgischem Recht </TC>
<FRMDEF NAME="ROMAN" PNTSZSTR="" FONTNAME="" FACE="R" SETWIDTHSTR="" SLANTSTR="" BASESTR="" COLORSTR="" SCREENSTR="" SMALLCAPS="2" ALLCAPS="2" KNOCKOUT="2" ENDFRM="1" SAVFRM="0" UNDLEAD1="" UNDLEAD2="" UNDTHICK1="" UNDTHICK2="" UNDCOLOR="" UNDSCREEN="" UNDLKNOCKOUT="1"/>
<FRMDEF NAME="ITALIC" PNTSZSTR="" FONTNAME="" FACE="I" SETWIDTHSTR="" SLANTSTR="" BASESTR="" COLORSTR="" SCREENSTR="" SMALLCAPS="2" ALLCAPS="2" KNOCKOUT="2" ENDFRM="0" SAVFRM="1" UNDLEAD1="" UNDLEAD2="" UNDTHICK1="" UNDTHICK2="" UNDCOLOR="" UNDSCREEN="" UNDLKNOCKOUT="1"/>
<TC>(soci&#233;t&#233; anonyme)</TC>
<FRMDEF NAME="ITALIC" PNTSZSTR="" FONTNAME="" FACE="I" SETWIDTHSTR="" SLANTSTR="" BASESTR="" COLORSTR="" SCREENSTR="" SMALLCAPS="2" ALLCAPS="2" KNOCKOUT="2" ENDFRM="1" SAVFRM="0" UNDLEAD1="" UNDLEAD2="" UNDTHICK1="" UNDTHICK2="" UNDCOLOR="" UNDSCREEN="" UNDLKNOCKOUT="1"/>
<FRMDEF NAME="ROMAN" PNTSZSTR="" FONTNAME="" FACE="R" SETWIDTHSTR="" SLANTSTR="" BASESTR="" COLORSTR="" SCREENSTR="" SMALLCAPS="2" ALLCAPS="2" KNOCKOUT="2" ENDFRM="0" SAVFRM="1" UNDLEAD1="" UNDLEAD2="" UNDTHICK1="" UNDTHICK2="" UNDCOLOR="" UNDSCREEN="" UNDLKNOCKOUT="1"/>
<TC> mit Sitz in Senningerberg, eingetragen im </TC>
</LINE>
<LINE>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you meet a hyphen, you need to:

1. Remove the last word from the previous line.
2. Begin a new line.
3. Copy the first word from the next line to the new line without space before.

The idea is to keep a variable of the "prefix" for the new line. I.E. if you have `blah-<newline>blahblah`, you'll see the "blah", setting it as the prefix for the next line, and when seeing the "blahblah", concatenating it to the "blah".

```py
text = prefix = ''
for block in root:
    for para in block:
        for line in para:
            for word in line:
                if word.tag == 'TC':
                    text += prefix + word.text
                    prefix = ''
                if word.tag == 'TCL' and word.attrib['CHAR']=='-':
                    # Find the last word
                    last_space_index = text.rfind(' ')
                    prefix = text[last_space_index + 1:]
                    text = text[:last_space_index]
```

Comment: Hi Chayim - Thank you for your response. I tried running this code however, it didn't give the desired result instead, it gave me the entire content as output. I am trying further to explore your code. In the meanwhile, do you have any suggestions on this??

Comment: Yeah, what did you want?

Comment: did you try running your code??? the text variable gives the entire content. I need the hyphenated word. In the example that I shared the output that is expected are 2 words (Ubernahme-angebot and Aktiengesell-schaft) in text variable.

Comment: Hi Chayim - Just to let you know, I have figured it out myself. In case, if you are still working (or yet to work) on this, you can ignore. If you have already completed it, please do share your code. Thank you for your help